sqlite3 и вопрос про бд в общем знающим людям
Я создал в своем приложении бд sqlite3 , получается, что для каждого нового пользователя сказавшего приложение, будет своя копия бд. Если я что-то туда добавлю, изменение будет только на моей копии бд. Как реализовать общую БД, хотя бы примерно, спасибо!

Sqlite позиционируется как локальная БД для хранения, например, промежуточных состояний программы, локальных настроек, грубо говоря - в рамках одного устройства. Как написано в документации:

SQLite - это встроенный механизм баз данных SQL. В отличие от большинства других баз данных SQL, SQLite не имеет отдельного серверного процесса.

Если Вам необходим совместный доступ к БД, стоит обратиться к клиент-серверным СУБД - MySql хотя бы
